# facebook reference from nuget packages in windows phone 8

Tags: facebook, reference, nuget

I'm trying to add facebook reference from nuget packages in my windows phone 8 application and I get this error:

Could not install package 'Facebook 6.1.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How can I solve this?

Thanks,
Hanna

Answer (score 2):

Update your Nuget from version 2.0 to 2.1 or 2.2. As Windows Phone 8 supports 2.1 and Higher version. And then insatll using Install-Package Facebook in Library package manager

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Targeting_Windows_8_and_Windows_Phone_8_Projects

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, except I was trying to add Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add packages to a Windows Phone 8 project which targets a specialized framework which comes with Windows Phone SDK. Facebook package you're trying to add targets good old .net framework.

Refer to the following link which gives more info on Windows Phone packages on nuget:

[Targeting Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Projects](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Targeting_Windows_8_and_Windows_Phone_8_Projects)